# Unexpected difference between loc and ix

Tags: python, pandas

I've noticed a strange difference between `loc` and `ix` when subsetting a DataFrame in Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,9,5,6,8], 'x1':[10.0,12.3,13.4,11.9,7.6], 'x2':['a','a','b','c','c']})
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)

df
      x1 x2
id         
10  10.0  a
9   12.3  a
5   13.4  b
6   11.9  c
8    7.6  c


df.loc[[10, 9, 7]] # 7 does not exist in the index so a NaN row is returned
df.loc[[7]] # KeyError: 'None of [[7]] are in the [index]'
df.ix[[7]] # 7 does not exist in the index so a NaN row is returned
```

Why does `df.loc[[7]]` throw an error while `df.ix[[7]]` returns a row with NaN? Is this a bug? If not, why are `loc` and `ix` designed this way?

(Note I'm using Pandas 0.17.1 on Python 3.5.1)

Comment: Decided this is most likely a bug.  Filed a report [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11840)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @shanmuga says, this is (at least for `loc`) **the intended and documented behaviour, and not a bug**.

The documentation on `loc`/selection by label, gives the rules on this (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label ):

> **At least 1** of the labels for which you ask, must be in the index or a KeyError will be raised!

This means using `loc` with a single label (eg `df.loc[[7]]`) will raise an error if this label is not in the index, but when using it with a list of labels (eg `df.loc[[7,8,9]]`) will not raise an error if at least one of those labels is in the index.

---

For `ix` I am less sure, and this is not clearly documented I think. But in any case, `ix` is much more permissive and has a lot of edge cases (fallback to integer position etc), and is rather a rabbit hole. But in general, `ix` will always return a result indexed with the provided labels (so does not check if the labels are in the index as `loc` does), *unless* it falls back to integer position indexing.
In most cases it is advised to use `loc`/`iloc`

Comment: What's so confusing is that `df.loc[[7,8,9]]` actually returns a row for id=7, but `df.loc[[7]]` does not.  I would have expected them to either both error, or for `df.loc[[7,8,9]]` to not return a row for id=7.  Nonetheless, I'm glad to know this isn't a bug.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this behavior is intended, not a bug.**
Although I couldn't find any official documentation, I found a comment by  **jreback on 21 Mar 2014**  to [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6683) indicating this.

> ix can very subtly give wrong results (use an index of say even numbers)
>
> you can use whatever function you want; ix is still there, but it doesn't provide the guarantees that loc provides, namely that it won't interpret a number as a location

**As for why it is designed so**
As mentioned in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

> .ix supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily label based, but will fall back to integer positional access unless the corresponding axis is of integer type.

In my opinion raising a `KeyError` would be ambiguous as whether it it came from index, or integer position. Instead `ix` returns `NaN` when given a list

Comment: But then why would `df.loc[[7]]` return an error and `df.loc[[10, 9, 7]]` return a dataframe with three rows?  What is the purpose of that?

Comment: `.loc` provides a guaranty that the values are present in the DataFrame index. However `.ix` does not guaranty this (it checks for both index before falling back to integer position). In such cases (IMHO) is better to giving `NaN` instead of raising a key error is better.

Comment: Again, why would `df.loc[[10, 9, 7]]` return three rows (i.e. including one for id=7 when no such id exists) if `.loc`provides a guaranty as you mention?

Comment: I agree, this is inconsistent behavior. And I couldn't find any documentation explaining this.